# How can I prevent the third box from being cut off when moving left in a component with three boxes using React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image]

Animation - third box is cut when moving left.

I want to add a component with three boxes which are moving right to left.

Third box is cut on larger screen and only first box is visible on smaller screen while they are moving.

How make them all visible?

I tried with different media query and it didn't help.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); 
  }
}

.wrapper.animated .container {
  animation: slideToLeft 30s linear infinite;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    font-size: 0; 
  }
  
  .box {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./Box.css";

function Box1() {
  const imageData = [
    {
      id: 1,

      text: "one",
    },
    {
      id: 2,

      text: "two",
    },
    {
      id: 3,

      text: "three",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div class="wrapper animated">
      <div className="container">
        {imageData.map((item) => (
          <div class="box" key={item.id}>
            <p>{item.text}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Box1;
```

Comment: Since this is a CSS question, please show a demo with HTML rather than JSX.